# Abaqus subroutine argument mismatch

Tags: linker, fortran, abaqus

I see an error in abaqus UMAT subroutine trying I’m trying to write.

That is:
This error may be due to a mismatch in the Abaqus user subroutine arguments.   These arguments sometimes change from release to release, so user subroutines   used with a previous release of Abaqus may need to be adjusted.

There is no linking problem since I run other codes and also I check this linkage by Command "verify-all" in abaqus command window.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: review your arguments against current documentation.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]. You mustvshow the code and the error messages. It is really important.

Answer (score 0):

First: Some arguments of the Vufield and Vusfld are different in abq2014 and abq2020.

Second: It seems that newer versions of abaqus have some kind of bug if you have a "STOP" command in any of your subroutines. You should remove this command. I had it in the subroutine which calculated the determinant while checking if it was singular.

I was trying to run some subroutines which were running successfully running in 2014  but in 2020 version - no status file was created and abaqus used to exit with error [while no errors messages were shown as you mentioned] Doing the above 2 things solved it for me.